# Is there a way to organize my Google sheet by 2 points in the same column?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, organization

I'm still fairly new to sheets and any excel format.

I'm trying to organize an ongoing form by Year and Season that our students are interested in starting in. I have the information displays as "Year Season" in each cell of the column (ie 2022 Winter).  I have the sheet organized ascending by the year in this column, but I'm wondering if there is a way to then secondarily order the sheet by season (Winter, Spring, Summer, Fall instead of the alphabetical order that asc puts them in).

I'd like to do this without separating the year and season into two separate columns but understand if that's not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

List the seasons in the order your wish in a specific tab called seasons

[image]

Then apply this formula to you data

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(A1:A="",,left(A1:A,4)&"-"&MATCH(MID(A1:A,6,len(A1:A)-4),seasons!A:A,0)))
```

so that you will be able to sort

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike! I'll try this out!